# Jersey JSON application builds, fails

Tags: java, json, rest, tomcat, jersey

I have a Java web application that exposes several REST endpoints. They all work. They can be hit and return the expected data (plain text). I need them to return JSON instead. To do this, the application needs to:

1. Include the "jersey-media-moxy" jar
2. Include `@XmlRootElement` atop any POJO we want converted to JSON

I added the `@XmlRootElement` to the class. Our project builds with gradle. I added this line to the bottom of the `dependencies` section of our build.gradle file:

```
compile group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.media', name: 'jersey-media-moxy', version: '2.26'
```

It looks almost identical to the line above it:

```
compile group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.media', name: 'jersey-media-multipart', version: '2.22.2'
```

Except for the name and version, of course. It builds fine. I had to add the jar (`jersey-media-moxy-2.26.jar`) to our dependency hierarchy, but no big deal.

It runs fine, until the user logs in. A number of components on the main screen are missing, and it spews errors (the application always spews errors, but they are expected). The new errors are varied, but a repeated one is:

```
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jersey/repackaged/com/google/common/base/Predicate
   at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:177)
   at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:369)
   at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
...
```

The stack trace never includes any of our source code as the culprit. It's all `org.glassfish.jersey` and `org.apache.catalina.core` errors (we are using Tomcat as our server). Clearly, something is wrong.

I've tried more things to resolve it than I like to recall, but some include:

- Adding the `jersey-media-moxy` in a different location of the 40 or so dependencies we have (**no difference**)
- Explicitly adding all the `jersey-media-moxy` dependencies (even though it builds fine without them; **no difference**)
- Removing the `jersey-media-multipart` dependency (**build fails**)
- Scrapping the workspace and doing a fresh "get" from source control, and re-adding the `jersey-media-moxy` dependency (**no difference**)
- Bringing the `jersey-media-multipart` up to the latest version (**doesn't build**)
- Removed the `jersey-media-moxy` dependency to see if I really need it (who knows? Maybe `jersey-media-multipart` already contains it) and changed the object I'm returning to a very simple class (it just contains a `string`). (**that fails**, it really does need `jersey-media-moxy`)

I am the only Java developer here, and this is the first time I've used gradle or Jersey. There are other ways to produce JSON, I know (such as using gson), but we really want to have Jersey do it, since we're using the framework already.

We use Eclipse (Oxygen) as our IDE and Tomcat as our server.

One big question I have is **why would a new jar break an existing one?**

The second question is the big one, of course: **what can I do to resolve this issue?**

Comment: Your 2.26 and 2.22.2 discrepancy is probably the problem. Don't mix your Jersey module versions.

Comment: Well, dang, @peeskilet, that was it! I wish you had posted this as the answer so I could mark it as such. Upping the version numbers to 2.26 didn't work, but downgrading to 2.22.2 did. Thanks a lot! I feel stupid for not knowing this, but I got a working app now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your 2.26 and 2.22.2 discrepancy is probably the problem. Don't mix your Jersey module versions.

> why would a new jar break an existing one?

Because it isn't just a single *jar* that you are adding. When using a dependency management system like with Maven or Gradle, you are dealing with *dependencies* not just *jars*, and the ones that you explicitly list can have their own dependencies that implicitly get pulled in. For instance if you were to just add `jersey-media-moxy`, it would pull in like 10+ extra jars.

The problem with this is that if you use incompatible version, both `jersey-media-moxy` and `jersey-media-multipart` pull in some of the same jars, put you can't have more than one version of a class. So only one of the classes from those two jars will be used. And as you know, software changes with version changes. So one class might be trying to use a class that exists in one version and not in another version. This is just one of the problems you can face if you don't manage your dependencies versions correctly.

Comment: As I mentioned above, this solved my problem. Changing all the versions to 2.22.2 fixed all the errors and enabled JSON in my application. Thanks for the more in-depth explanation.